# is there no way to save data from block to a property or outside object in ios obj-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4

I have designed a class "AsyncHttpRequest" for asynchronous http request handling and the class initializer takes a block as a parameter.

The block is called from "AsyncHttpRequest" classes's following delegate implementation :

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

   NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization
        JSONObjectWithData:_dataResponseData //1
                   options:kNilOptions
                     error:&error];

   myBlock(dict);
```

}

and I am creating instance of the above class from a view controller like the following

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
__block NSDictionary *myDic; 

AsyncHttpRequest *r = [[AsyncHttpRequest alloc] initWithUrl:urlStr withBlock:^(NSDictionary *d){

        NSLog(@"List = %@",d);  //Its working
        NSDictionary *locDic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:d]; 
         // the above is working

        myDic = d; //not working

        myDic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:locDic]; 
            // The above code is not working..   
     }];
}
```

It is giving the following error : 
       error: address doesn't contain a section that points to a section in a object file

is there no way to save data from block to a property or outside object in obj-c?

Thank you....I have been trying this for last 3 hours and not getting any solution.

Thanks

Comment: Everything that you wrote works, there's only a syntax error when closing the block.

Comment: Unrelated but make sure to wrap your `myBlock(dict);` call in an if statement that checks to make sure that it isn't nil: `if(myBlock!=nil){myBlock(dict);}` (note the lack of parentheses after myBlock in the if statement). If you attempt to call myBlock() and it's NULL it'll crash your app.

Comment: No...its not working...otherwise why I would search the topic for last 3 hours?

Comment: It is giving the following error : error: address doesn't contain a section that points to a section in a object file

Comment: Are you declaring `myDic` in the same scope you are creating the `AsyncHttpRequest`? If so you will need to make it a member variable so that it is not out of scope by the time the async operation completes.

Comment: @Joe I have updated the 2nd code block. Thank you...

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  What behaviour do you see?  Where do you see the error message?  Is it at run-time?  Compile-time?  Is it relating to a particular line of code?  Is the code here an exact copy and paste, and if so, where is `error` defined for the first section of code?

Comment: I see the error message at run-time. Whenever I am assigning the response block parameter to a variable outside of the block, I am getting the above error. Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's possible that the `myDic` is being deallocated before it's being used.

Here's my reasoning, `-[AsyncHttpRequest initWithUrl:withBlock:]` captures the block, but `myDic` is not retained. At some point in the future, the `connectionDidFinishLoading` method is called, but by then the `myDic` variable is now out of scope as it's been deallocated.

Makes sense?

If this is the case, then possible solutions may include:

- retain `myDic` before passing it to the `-[AsyncHttpRequest initWithUrl:withBlock:]` method. Note: `myDic` should be an instance variable/
- create a `NSDictionary` property on `AsyncHttpRequest` and set the property to `myDic`.

Comment: I have tried both of your proposed solution. But I am still getting the run-time error : address doesn't contain a section that points to a section in a object file

Comment: @sudip, for options 1 to work, myDic has to be an member variable of the class.

Comment: I just checked one thing. If I access any object declared outside of the block, I am getting runtime error. But, accessing or assigning any  object inside the block is valid. I am new to ios programming. is it desired behavior? Thank uuu..

Comment: No, that's isn't desired. I don't understand what you mean by "...access any object declared outside of the block...". Where are you accessing the object? Have you tried Joe's suggestion? The `myDic` should be in the `@interface YourViewController:UIViewController { __block NSDictionary *myDic; } @end` and not in the `-(void) viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I think I have found the solution. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

If a block is called from a delegate method implementation, then its giving error.

In my example,

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection { 
   ............
   ....... 
   myBlock(...);
 }
```

is a implementation of NSURLConnectionDataDelegate and I have called the block function from inside the above method.

It was giving unexpected result,i.e., any variable or object(property or instance variable) that are declared outside the block function cant be accessed from within the block. For ex.,

```
__block NSDictionary *myDic; 

AsyncHttpRequest *r = [[AsyncHttpRequest alloc] initWithUrl:urlStr withBlock:^(NSDictionary *d){
    NSLog(@"List = %@",d);  //Its working
    NSLog(@"List = %@",myDic); //not working


 }];
```

In the above code, myDic is declared outside the block and accessing it is giving runtime error.

Somebody has down voted my question without understanding it and I will really appreciate it if someone make it right.

Thank you....

Comment: :so, what was your solution?